# How do I get the input components for a merge join to be sorted in SSIS when using biml?

Tags: ssis, biml

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<Packages>
    <Package Name="Extraction_RecordCount" ConstraintMode="Parallel">
        <Tasks>
            <ExecuteSQL Name="Extraction_RecordCount" ConnectionName="Target">
                <DirectInput> <![CDATA[ Truncate table CMC.Extraction_RecordCount ]]> </DirectInput>
            </ExecuteSQL>
            <Dataflow Name="Fill Extraction_RecordCount">
                <PrecedenceConstraints>
                    <Inputs>
                        <Input OutputPathName="Extraction_RecordCount.Output" />
                    </Inputs>
                </PrecedenceConstraints>
                <Transformations>
                    <OleDbSource Name="ExtractedTables" ConnectionName="Target" >
                        <DirectInput>
                            <![CDATA[
                            SELECT cast( sysobjects.NAME as nvarchar(128)) as TableName 
                                ,sysindexes.Rows as #Rows 
                            FROM sysobjects 
                            INNER JOIN sysindexes ON sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id 
                            INNER JOIN ( SELECT c.table_name ,c.table_schema FROM information_schema.columns c GROUP BY c.table_name ,c.table_schema) c ON c.table_name = sysobjects.NAME 
                            WHERE type = 'U' 
                                AND sysindexes.IndId < 2 
                                AND c.table_schema = 'EXT' 
                            ORDER BY TableName, #Rows
                            ]]>
                        </DirectInput>
                    </OleDbSource>
                    <OleDbSource Name="BackOffice" ConnectionName="Source" >
                        <DirectInput> <![CDATA[ select TABLE_NAME  , cast(NUM_ROWS as int) as NUM_ROWS from ALL_ALL_TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS]]> </DirectInput>
                    </OleDbSource>
                    <MergeJoin Name="Join Extracted Tables w BACKOFFICE" JoinType="InnerJoin">
                        <LeftInputPath OutputPathName="ExtractedTables.Output">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column SourceColumn="TableName" SortKeyPosition="1"/>
                                <Column SourceColumn="#Rows" SortKeyPosition="2"/>
                            </Columns>
                        </LeftInputPath>
                        <RightInputPath OutputPathName="BackOffice.Output">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column SourceColumn="TABLE_NAME" SortKeyPosition="1"/>
                                <Column SourceColumn="NUM_ROWS" SortKeyPosition="2" />
                            </Columns>
                        </RightInputPath>
                        <JoinKeys>
                            <JoinKey LeftColumn="TableName" RightColumn="TABLE_NAME" />
                        </JoinKeys>
                    </MergeJoin>
                    <OleDbDestination Name="Extraction_RecordCount" ConnectionName="Target">
                        <ExternalTableOutput Table="CMC.Extraction_RecordCount"/>
                    </OleDbDestination>
                </Transformations>
            </Dataflow>
        </Tasks>
    </Package>
</Packages>
```

This code does generate the package 'Extraction_RecordCount'but an error is thrown by the 'Merge Join '-component stating that the imput of both sources must be sorted. Manually setting 'IsSorted' = 'True' and setting the 'SortKeyPosition' solves the problem temporary.

Inserting Sort-components won't work either.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77666/ssis-get-max-value-in-column-and-create-new-column While I read your exact question, you can crib from my answer over on DBA.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement for a Merge Join is that your sources are sorted. What your current code is specifying is that the output of the Merge Join transformation is sorted. Instead, you want to indicate that the input for the Merge Join is sorted.

Your source data is sorted, I see both have explicit `ORDER BY` operations in them. What you're missing is the specification that the source component is sorted.

```
                <OleDbSource Name="ExtractedTables" ConnectionName="Target" >
                    <DirectInput>
                        <![CDATA[
                        SELECT cast( sysobjects.NAME as nvarchar(128)) as TableName 
                            ,sysindexes.Rows as #Rows 
                        FROM sysobjects 
                        INNER JOIN sysindexes ON sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id 
                        INNER JOIN ( SELECT c.table_name ,c.table_schema FROM information_schema.columns c GROUP BY c.table_name ,c.table_schema) c ON c.table_name = sysobjects.NAME 
                        WHERE type = 'U' 
                            AND sysindexes.IndId < 2 
                            AND c.table_schema = 'EXT' 
                        ORDER BY TableName, #Rows
                        ]]>
                    </DirectInput>
                     <Columns>
                         <Column SourceColumn="TableName" SortKeyPosition="1"></Column>
                         <Column SourceColumn="#Rows" SortKeyPosition="2"></Column>
                     </Columns>
                </OleDbSource>
                <OleDbSource Name="BackOffice" ConnectionName="Source" >
                    <DirectInput> <![CDATA[ select TABLE_NAME  , cast(NUM_ROWS as int) as NUM_ROWS from ALL_ALL_TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS]]> </DirectInput>
                        <Columns>
                            <Column SourceColumn="TABLE_NAME" SortKeyPosition="1"></Column>
                            <Column SourceColumn="NUM_ROWS" SortKeyPosition="2"></Column>
                        </Columns>
                </OleDbSource>
```

I'm not 100% that the actual name of `#Rows` in your first query is going to be valid but the important thing is to mark it as sorted by the column name

There's a full end-to-end Merge Join example over on my answer for this DBA.StackExchange.com question

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77666/ssis-get-max-value-in-column-and-create-new-column